# .SetFocus from module VBA

Tags: vba, module, setfocus

I'm trying to set the focus in a form after update. When I do this within the forms class module I have no problem. However, I need to do this in a few forms so I'm trying to write it in the module. My problem is I can't get the .SetFocus to work unless I hardcode the form name within the class module. WHno is the name of the control I'm trying to set focus.

I have attempted a number of options and none seem to work.

Here is the sub. Everything works wonderfully except the .SetFocus procedure.

```
Sub ValidateWHNO()

Dim EnteredWHNO As Integer
Dim actForm As String
Dim deWHNO As Variant
msg As Integer
Dim ctrlWHNO As Control

EnteredWHNO = Screen.ActiveControl.Value
actForm = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
Set ctrlWHNO = [Forms]![frmEnterBookData]![WHno]
deWHNO = DLookup("[WHno]", "tblDataEntry", "[WHno] = " & EnteredWHNO)

If EnteredWHNO = deWHNO Then
    msg = MsgBox("You have already entered " & EnteredWHNO & " as a WHNO. The next number is " & DMax("[WHno]", "tblDataEntry") + 1 & ", use this?", 4 + 64, "Already Used WHno!")
    If msg = 6 Then
        Screen.ActiveControl.Value = DMax("[WHno]", "tblDataEntry") + 1
    Else
        Screen.ActiveControl.Value = Null
        ctrlWHNO.SetFocus 'CODE THAT WONT RUN
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I've tried a number of other methods to set focus, such as:
`Forms(actForm).WHno.SetFocus`, 
`Forms(actForm).Controls(WHno).SetFocus`, `Screen.ActiveControl.SetFocus`

The current result is that if No is selected in the MsgBox, the value is cleared, but the focus moves to the next control.

Thanks in advanced for any help that may be offered.

Comment: Is the `WHno` control enabled? (i.e. not disabled)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following make a difference?

```
Sub ValidateWHNO(frm as Access.Form)

    Dim EnteredWHNO As Integer
    Dim actForm As String
    Dim deWHNO As Variant
    msg As Integer

    EnteredWHNO = frm.ActiveControl.Value
    actForm = frm.Name
    deWHNO = DLookup("[WHno]", "tblDataEntry", "[WHno] = " & EnteredWHNO)

    If EnteredWHNO = deWHNO Then
        msg = MsgBox("You have already entered " & EnteredWHNO & " as a WHNO. The next number is " & DMax("[WHno]", "tblDataEntry") + 1 & ", use this?", 4 + 64, "Already Used WHno!")
        If msg = 6 Then
            frm.ActiveControl.Value = DMax("[WHno]", "tblDataEntry") + 1
        Else
            frm.ActiveControl.Value = Null
            frm![WHno].SetFocus
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

And your call from each form would be:

```
VaidateWHNO Me
```

Instead of using a relative reference to the form (Screen.ActiveForm), the code passes the form reference through directly and uses that reference as the parent of the .setFocus method.